# PHP retrieve footnotes of pages on DOCX

Tags: php

i'm trying to convert DOCX to html, after search on google i can find this simple library as this convertor from https://github.com/xylude/Docx-to-HTML/blob/master/docx_reader.php , but that couldn't detect `footnote` on pages and i'm trying to add that to this library,

how can i detect styled text or simple text is/are footnote?  that have special style?

```
<?php
class Docx_reader {
    private $fileData = false;
    private $errors = array();
    private $styles = array();
    public function __construct() {

    }
    private function load($file) {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $openedZip = $zip->open($file);
            if ($openedZip === true) {
                //attempt to load styles:
                if (($styleIndex = $zip->locateName('word/styles.xml')) !== false) {
                    $stylesXml = $zip->getFromIndex($styleIndex);
                    $xml = simplexml_load_string($stylesXml);
                    $namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
                    $children = $xml->children($namespaces['w']);
                    foreach ($children->style as $s) {
                        $attr = $s->attributes('w', true);
                        if (isset($attr['styleId'])) {
                            $tags = array();
                            $attrs = array();
                            foreach (get_object_vars($s->rPr) as $tag => $style) {
                                $att = $style->attributes('w', true);
                                switch ($tag) {
                                    case "b":
                                        $tags[] = 'strong';
                                        break;
                                    case "i":
                                        $tags[] = 'em';
                                        break;
                                    case "color":
                                        //echo (String) $att['val'];
                                        $attrs[] = 'color:#' . $att['val'];
                                        break;
                                    case "sz":
                                        $attrs[] = 'font-size:' . $att['val'] . 'px';
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            $styles[(String)$attr['styleId']] = array('tags' => $tags, 'attrs' => $attrs);
                        }
                    }
                    $this->styles = $styles;
                }
                if (($index = $zip->locateName('word/document.xml')) !== false) {
                    // If found, read it to the string
                    $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
                    // Close archive file
                    $zip->close();
                    return $data;
                }
                $zip->close();
            }
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = 'File does not exist.';
        }
    }
    public function setFile($path) {
        $this->fileData = $this->load($path);
    }
    public function to_plain_text() {
        if ($this->fileData) {
            return strip_tags($this->fileData);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function to_html() {
        if ($this->fileData) {
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($this->fileData);
            $namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
            $children = $xml->children($namespaces['w']);
            $html = '<!doctype html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /><title></title><style>span.block { display: block; }</style></head><body>';
            foreach ($children->body->p as $p) {
                $style = '';

                $startTags = array();
                $startAttrs = array();

                if($p->pPr->pStyle) {                    
                    $objectAttrs = $p->pPr->pStyle->attributes('w',true);
                    $objectStyle = (String) $objectAttrs['val'];
                    if(isset($this->styles[$objectStyle])) {
                        $startTags = $this->styles[$objectStyle]['tags'];
                        $startAttrs = $this->styles[$objectStyle]['attrs'];
                    }
                }

                if ($p->pPr->spacing) {
                    $att = $p->pPr->spacing->attributes('w', true);
                    if (isset($att['before'])) {
                        $style.='padding-top:' . ($att['before'] / 10) . 'px;';
                    }
                    if (isset($att['after'])) {
                        $style.='padding-bottom:' . ($att['after'] / 10) . 'px;';
                    }
                }
                $html.='<span class="block" style="' . $style . '">';
                $li = false;
                if ($p->pPr->numPr) {
                    $li = true;
                    $html.='<li>';
                }

                foreach ($p->r as $part) {
                    //echo $part->t;
                    $tags = $startTags;
                    $attrs = $startAttrs;                                        
                    foreach (get_object_vars($part->pPr) as $k => $v) {
                        if ($k = 'numPr') {
                            $tags[] = 'li';
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (get_object_vars($part->rPr) as $tag => $style) {
                        //print_r($style->attributes());
                        $att = $style->attributes('w', true);
                        switch ($tag) {
                            case "b":
                                $tags[] = 'strong';
                                break;
                            case "i":
                                $tags[] = 'em';
                                break;
                            case "color":
                                //echo (String) $att['val'];
                                $attrs[] = 'color:#' . $att['val'];
                                break;
                            case "sz":
                                $attrs[] = 'font-size:' . $att['val'] . 'px';
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    $openTags = '';
                    $closeTags = '';
                    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                        $openTags.='<' . $tag . '>';
                        $closeTags.='</' . $tag . '>';
                    }
                    $html.='<span style="' . implode(';', $attrs) . '">' . $openTags . $part->t . $closeTags . '</span>';
                }
                if ($li) {
                    $html.='</li>';
                }
                $html.="</span>";
            }
            //Trying to weed out non-utf8 stuff from the file:
            $regex = <<<'END'
/
  (
    (?: [\x00-\x7F]                 # single-byte sequences   0xxxxxxx
    |   [\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]      # double-byte sequences   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
    |   [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}   # triple-byte sequences   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx * 2
    |   [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}   # quadruple-byte sequence 11110xxx 10xxxxxx * 3 
    ){1,100}                        # ...one or more times
  )
| .                                 # anything else
/x
END;
            preg_replace($regex, '$1', $html);
            return $html . '</body></html>';
            exit();
        }
    }
    public function get_errors() {
        return $this->errors;
    }
    private function getStyles() {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is gonna be hard to answer without a lot of research. Your best bet is to create a docx with a footnote, and extract the file using any archive tool. You'll see that in the end it's plain XML. You then find your foot note and go from here. You can see that the XML is turned into a PHP object, so you'll be able to play with that to reach the values you are looking for.